# Retrofit2 Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT Reddit JSON response

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit2

Before I start, I want to apologize for repeating the question but I just want to get better understanding of how this works because I've looked around but wasn't able to find an answer related to my JSON response.

This is the JSON response I am trying to read with Retrofit2.
(https://www.reddit.com/r/popular.json)

```
{
    kind: "Listing",
    data: {
        modhash: "9nsu2iqwupcf7d47e57c6f70795c9fde52e5566bf8b7731884",
        children: [
            {
                kind: "t3",
                data: {}
            },
            {
                kind: "t3",
                data: {}
            },
            {
                kind: "t3",
                data: {}
            },

            And so on...
```

I am new to programming and I've worked in the past with Retrofit for couple of my small projects. In those projects I was easily able to download the data as I always encountered with Array at start but in this case, it's Object.

I've just updated the classes with POJO to create the JSON Response structure yet it's still not returning anything after going into debug mode. If you need any further information, please let me know. Really appreciate your help guys

```
public void getPopularPost() {
    popularPosts = new ArrayList<>();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://www.reddit.com/")
            .build();

    FromAPI fromAPI = retrofit.create(FromAPI.class);
    final Call<Rootobject> call = fromAPI.getPopularPosts();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Rootobject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Rootobject> call, Response<Rootobject> response) {
            response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Rootobject> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

===========================================================================

```
public interface FromAPI {

    @GET("r/popular.json")
    Call<Rootobject> getPopularPosts();

}
```

===========================================================================

```
public class Rootobject {
    private String kind;
    private Data data;
}

public class Data {
    private String modhash;
    private ArrayList<Child> children;
//    private String after;
//    private Object before;    
}

public class Child {   
    private String kind;
    private Data2 data;    
}

public class Data2 {    
    private String domain;
    private String author;
    private String title;
    private int num_comments;
    private int ups;
    private String url;    
}
```

Comment: your pojo class doesn't hold the structure of the json response.

Comment: Thanks for the response Manoj but can you please explain the pojo structure to me in this case? That's what I am trying to figure out. I have a slight idea like this:- ResponseHandle class with String kind and String data, Children class with String modhash and ArrayList<Post>children

Comment: http://json2java.azurewebsites.net/ use this site to generate pojo classes from url response. That will get you to solution.

Comment: You called `response.body()` and are doing nothing with it... Why are you expecting something to happen there?

Comment: In the debug mode, I've put a break point on the response.body() to see if it contains anything but it skips the method and I cannot seem to locate the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto this site [Json To Java Pojo](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/) paste the entire json there,it will show you all the pojo classes that need to be created.You are probably missing a few or have created some incorrectly.

Comment: might be stupid question to ask but do i need to create classes which i do not want to use but are in the Json?

Comment: @Nero not a stupid question, i genuinely am not sure about it but by my understanding,if you need something at the lowest level of the json tree,you need to create pojo for each and every level above it.

Comment: @Nero The error is definitely in the json and pojo classes,creating each and every class and then try would work for sure and then you could try eliminating classe based on your requirements and see if it still works

Comment: @Nero did you have to create all the classes for it to work?

Comment: Yes I did, every class is necessary I think regardless if u r going to use it or not